# Methods to test Unity WebGL multiplayer game server scalability

Tags: unity-game-engine, testing, unity-webgl

I am looking for a method to test the scalability of my WebGL multiplayer game (built in Unity 3D). The game is currently based on the PUN (Photon Unity Network) library and cloud service for multiplayer communication. I would like to know how to efficiently find out if the server hardware and architecture can support, let's say, 20, 50, or even 100 players in one room, with the limited number of computers at my disposal. Ideally I would like to know the frame rate each player will experience. I do have access to some powerful servers. A preliminary idea I have now is to run a bunch of virtual machines on these servers, each of which runs a browser tab with the game. Just want to know the industry practice or what you think would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Framerate is hardware dependent and if you are sending data to the server EVERY frame you are doing it wrong.

Basic premise on doing it right would be, a player shoots a projectile..

Get its spawnpoint, direction and speed and then pass that to the other players/server to then process without the need to send data each frame.

This is a simplified example but gets the point across.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great point for increasing scalability and I will make changes to the project accordingly. Besides this, I am interested in how I should test if the game actually scale? I mean, I only have a handful of computers, how can I know if the server actually supports (for example) >30 concurrent players? Any useful metrics? Thanks!

Comment: Check [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17542/how-to-check-if-a-gameserver-can-handle-clients-before-game-release) out, I think it's what you are asking.